# Meshlab: how to select vertex by color

Tags: meshlab

I want to select vertex by color. At the moment I want to select the cells with (R,G,B)=(0,0,0). What function should I write?

r=0 and g=0 and b=0 doens't work.

And if I want to pick (R,G,B)=(255,255,255)? Or any other combination?

This question might be strange but I guess these colors don't vary between 0 and 255. They seem to vary between 0 and 1 instead.

Regards

Maria

Answer (score 3):

You need to use r == 0 instead of r = 0 for "equals". This has been fixed in the 2016.12 documentation I believe, but is incorrect in older versions. MeshLab uses the muparser library for its filter functions; you can view all the built-in functions and operators [here](http://beltoforion.de/article.php?a=muparser&hl=en&p=features&s=idDef2#idDef2).

Also, MeshLab does use color values in the range 0-255.